# Beginning Python(2.7.8) O'Reilly Video Series Exercise

Tags: python

I am trying to complete an exercise in O'Reilly's Beginning Python Video series.  My code appears (to me at least) to replicate the example from the video however I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "blackjack.py", line 20, in <module> print(d.deal())

File "blackjack.py", line 15, in deal return self.cards.pop()

AttributeError: 'deck' object has no attribute 'cards'
```

Here's the code that I normally use:

```
import random

class deck(object):
    def shuffle(self):
        suits = ['Spades','Hearts','Clubs','Diamonds']
        ranks = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']
        self.cards = []
        for x in suits:
            for y in ranks:
                self.cards.append(y + x)

        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

d = deck()
d.shuffle

print(d.deal())
print(d.deal())
```

Seems like it would have something to do with my `self.cards` list variable.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You're not *calling* `d.shuffle` which seems to initialize `self.cards` - you're missing a set of parentheses: `self.shuffle()`

Comment: Once spent four hours debugging why my database wasn't recording things. Eventually someone pointed out I had written `db.commit` where I should have written `db.commit()`. Sheepish? I should say so.

Comment: Wow. I feel pretty stupid right now.  Thanks, I will delete as to not waste anyone elses time.

Comment: @Buffy135, don't sweat it, it is an easy mistake to make anytime not just starting out

Answer (score 2):

```
d.shuffle() # is missing  parens
```

You need to call the `method`  `d.shuffle()` with parens.

```
In [3]: d = deck()

In [4]: d.shuffle
Out[4]: <bound method deck.shuffle of <__main__.deck object at 0x7fb8a4a04d10>>

In [5]: print(d.deal())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a5c7b7294801> in <module>()
----> 1 print(d.deal())

<ipython-input-2-0b86145ed058> in deal(self)
     13 
     14     def deal(self):
---> 15         return self.cards.pop()

AttributeError: 'deck' object has no attribute 'cards'

In [6]: d.shuffle()  # call the method

In [7]: print(d.deal()) # now all good
AHearts
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling `shuffle()`. You need the parenthesis.

`shuffle()` is a class method because of this it needs the parenthesis after it's name. You can access class attributes with out parenthesis but methods must have them.